# I need a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to match things like:

> Presse- und Informationsdienste

> Menschen- und Tieropfer

This is what I have but obviously I am doing something wrong:

```
[a-zA-Z]+- und [a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: Please make an attempt by yourself and show  us your attempt before asking for any help.

Comment: Why you want to match only the above strings?

Comment: Edit by @chipChocolate.py is incorrect.

Comment: @vks - Yes, I know. I realized that after I edited it and now there is one edit in the queue. I was waiting on it to get cleared.

Comment: What's wrong with the regex you posted? It matches both strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z]+-\s+und\s+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

You were close.Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/13

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^[a-zA-Z]+-\s+und\s+[a-zA-Z]+$', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"Presse- und Informationsdienste\nMenschen- und Tieropfer"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```
^\w+-\s+und\s+\w+$
```